# Blender Network Render Timeout

Tags: python, sockets, blender

I've tried to render a animation using Network Render. I connected my PC an my Laptop without further problems. But when I clicked "Render animation on network" after some seconds the following error occurs:

```
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.74\scripts\addons\netrender\operat ors.py", line 85, in invoke
return self.execute(context)
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.74\scripts\addons\netrender\operat ors.py", line 77, in execute
scene.network_render.job_id = client.sendJob(conn, scene, True)
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.74\scripts\addons\netrender\client .py", line 121, in sendJob
return sendJobBlender(conn, scene, anim, can_save)
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.74\scripts\addons\netrender\client .py", line 340, in sendJobBlender
response = conn.getresponse()
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.74\python\lib\http\client.py", line 1172, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.74\python\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.74\python\lib\http\client.py", line 313, in _read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
File "F:\Program Files (x86)\Blender\2.74\python\lib\socket.py", line 371, inreadinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

I asked Google: Somebody circumvents the problem by changing "[the default timeout to 1000 (instead of 300) (in the socket.py file[...])](https://developer.blender.org/T43966)". I can't find this line, I guess they changed it in the current version. Since I have no experience using python I do not know how I can change it now.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

The addon would be a better place to make the change instead of the socket module. If you look in your addons folder you will find [`netrender/utils.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/netrender/utils.py) where you will find a few lines that use `socket.setdefaulttimeout` and you could make some adjustments there.

An even better solution would be to look at why the connection is timing out, two computers in the same room should not get any timeouts. A common cause of timeouts is the inability to get a connection, firewalls are good at stopping connections, so you may want to check that the port used by network render is allowing incoming connections, and that blender is running with network render turned on to accept the connection. The default port is 8000 which could also be in use by another application, you can configure each computer to use a different port if needed.